# Controls from external library not appearing in Telerik project

Tags: wpf, user-controls, telerik, controls, controltemplate

I'm working on a project that uses Telerik WPF controls (in so called NoXaml mode) and I have a library with controls I would like to use. These are simple WPF UserControls without even any template and contain only standard WPF controls placed inside them (and some logic). All these controls used inside are covered by Telerik templates and work outside of these UserControls. The library works everywhere, except in this Telerik project, in which the controls just don't appear, they are blank. Even a simplest `<TextBlock>` inside such control is invisible. Drilling down with Snoop sometimes makes them magically appear.

I've read that Telerik projects need to define templates for any custom controls that you create in them, but I'd like the library to be in control of the look of these controls, so my question is:

Can I actually use a custom UserControl library in a Telerik project without having to write my own control templates for them? If so, how to do that? If not, any other simple workarounds?
Thanks.

Comment: A little confused here.  Are you saying that the Telerik controls are not appearing or that controls from some other (non-Telerik) library are not appearing?

Comment: The controls from external library - which are btw built from standard WPF controls (inside UserControls), which are working fine with Telerik templates outside of these external library controls. The same controls work fine if placed manually.